# Including Description with Page Layout

Tags: 2010, feature, visual-studio, branding

I'm deploying a couple of custom page layouts as part of a feature for SharePoint 2010, and am having issues including the description with the page layout. I'm looking to include descriptive text as illustrated below.

[image: Page Layout Description]

I've tried adding a description property to my XML, but that doesn't seem to work. I have found that if I edit the page layout properties in SharePoint after it's deployed, and type something in the description field, it will render as shown in the image. Is there some other property other than "Description" that should be used in the elements.xml? Everything deploys and works as expected, but the description is left blank.

Here's a copy of the XML I'm currently using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPageGallery" Path="MasterPageGallery" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Url="ApplicationLayout.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Application Layout" />
      <Property Name="Description" Value="Full screen iFrame; Use this layout to include other web applications inside SharePoint" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/ApplicationLayout.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/CustomPageLayout.png" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_articlepage_name;;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"/>
    </File>
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The internal name for "Description" is "MasterPageDescription".

Try that instead.